# How set the charset of dynamic form to UTF-8?

Tags: javascript

I have a form created dynamically with one input:

```
var myForm = document.createElement('form');
myForm.setAttribute('id', 'formDynamically');   
myForm.method = 'POST';
myForm.action = 'myAction';

var myInput = document.createElement('input');
myInput.type = 'text';
myInput.name = 'textDescription';
myInput.value = $('#myTextField').text();
myForm.appendChild(myInput);    

document.body.appendChild(myForm);
myForm.submit();
```

My problem is:

If the user types a text with accentuation, in the server the letters arrive strange

Exemple: 
'fiancé'. in the server side i recived ---> 'fiancÃ©'

obs: I can't change anything in server side.

obs²: I tried it with Jquery Ajax and works fine, the problem really is with my form (i can't use ajax, i must do it with form submit).

Any help is welcome !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
myForm.acceptCharset = "UTF-8";
```

[Documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_form_acceptcharset.asp)